# Monomials not in an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R=\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ denote the commutative ring of polynomials in two variables $x,y$ with real coefficients. Show that for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a monomial of degree $k$ **not** belonging to the ideal generated in $R$ by $p(x,y)=x^2+y^2$.

P.S. I know the elements of the ideal are of the form $q(x,y)(x^2+y^2)$ for $q(x,y)\in R$. I'm trying to prove, for example, that $x^k$ is not of that form. I'm asking for the reason why... (it must be some obvious thing i cant see)

Comment: What monomials *are* in the ideal?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Math.SE.  It's more helpful not to ask your question as an exercise, but to tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: What is the form of elements in a principal ideal of a commutative rings?

Comment: Hint: $\bf R$ is an integral domain.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x^k = q(x,y)(x^2+y^2)$.

$q$ has no $y^n$ term, otherwise the product would have $y^{n+2}$. Similarly, $q$ has no $x^ny^m$ term. So $q$ is a polynomial in $x$, but this too is impossible. Therefore, $x^k$ is not in the ideal.

In fact, you can convince yourself in a similar manner that all nonzero elements of the ideal are at least binomial.